# PendingIntent from Notifications are not coming back to service. Showing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, android-pendingintent, foreground-service

I have created a foreground service hence implemented notifications with PendingIntents.

The Notification is also showing.

But the pause and stop buttons are not working. When I click on it, the app crashes. When I click on play my log is printed means it is working fine.

The error it returns is like:

```
2021-06-20 23:40:24.167 25285-25285/com.example.startedservice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.startedservice, PID: 25285
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.startedservice.Service.MusicPlayerBoundService@2cdba7d with Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.startedservice/.Service.MusicPlayerBoundService bnds=[382,1495][698,1639] }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4001)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.startedservice.Service.MusicPlayerBoundService.onStartCommand(MusicPlayerBoundService.java:52)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3968)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7178) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

My onStartCommand() method:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String temp =intent.getAction();

    switch(temp){

        case "PLAY": {
            Log.d("MyTag", "play called");
            play();
            break;
        }

        case "PAUSE": {
            Log.d("MyTag", "pause called");
            pause();
            break;
        }

        case "START": {
            createNotificationChannel();
            showNotification();
            break;
        }

        case "STOP": {
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
            break;
        }

        default:
            stopSelf();


    }

    Log.d("MyTag","onStartCommand Called");
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

createNotificationChannel():

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    "ForegroundServiceChannel",
                    "Foreground Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
```

showNotification():

```
private void showNotification(){

    Notification.Builder builder = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),"ForegroundServiceChannel");
    }

   
    Intent play = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlayerBoundService.class);
    play.setAction("PLAY");

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),100,play,0);



    Intent pause = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlayerBoundService.class);
    play.setAction("PAUSE");

    PendingIntent paIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),100,pause,0);


    Intent stop = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlayerBoundService.class);
    play.setAction("STOP");

    PendingIntent sIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),100,stop,0);



    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("My Song is playing").setContentTitle("Meri Duniya")
    .addAction(new Notification.Action(R.drawable.play,"Play",pIntent))
    .addAction(new Notification.Action(R.drawable.pause,"Pause",paIntent))
    .addAction(new Notification.Action(R.drawable.stop,"Stop",sIntent));



    Notification notification = builder.build();
    startForeground(9,notification);

}
```

I have also given permissions in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
Intent pause = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlayerBoundService.class);
play.setAction("PAUSE");

PendingIntent paIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),100,pause,0);


Intent stop = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlayerBoundService.class);
play.setAction("STOP");
```

You aren't setting the `ACTION` on the correct variable for PAUSE and STOP. You need this:

```
Intent pause = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlayerBoundService.class);
pause.setAction("PAUSE");

PendingIntent paIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),100,pause,0);


Intent stop = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicPlayerBoundService.class);
stop.setAction("STOP");
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful you can "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This gives me some reputation points and improves your accept rate and will help others who come looking for answers.